# Why does pipenv cause issues?

Tags: python

The following code proiduces the followiung error.

```
 pipenv install requests
pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the   
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and    
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pipenv install requests
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipenv:String) [], Comm  
   andNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have tried changing the python interpreter to the venv one and the global ones but to no avail. Any idea why?

I install pipenv using code: 'pip install pipenv' and I am a Windows User

Comment: This is your shell not recognizing the program pipenv and not a pipenv error. What system are you on and how did you install pipenv?

Comment: +1 to the inquiry raised by @user8408080 and it will make people easier to answer the original question.

Comment: Hi its been updated in the original post. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, the directory that `pipenv` was installed to is not in your `PATH`. Adding it probably isn't a great idea either, as it risks conflicts between versions of Python.

The usual suggestion on Windows is to use [the Windows launcher](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/), `py.exe`, rather than relying on all the various executables being visible in `PATH`. Assuming you installed Python as an administrator and left the box for the launcher install checked, `py.exe` is available and can be used to launch arbitrary modules. So in this case, rather than running:

```
pipenv install requests
```

you'd run:

```
py -3 -mpipenv install requests
```

changing `-3` to some other installed version of Python (e.g. `-3.7`) if you didn't want to use the latest installed version of Python. You'd do the same thing when installing `pipenv` in the first place with `pip` to ensure the versions matched, e.g. replacing:

```
pip install pipenv
```

with:

```
py -3 -mpip install pipenv
```

Comment: Hiya thanks for the help but It still does not allow the importing of the 'requests' module although I installed it using your line of code. Error = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/muham/PyYelp/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: @Amen have you activated the pipenv you installed `requests` in?

Comment: Adding to @user8408080, that should be done with `py -3 -mpipenv shell`.